# Android avdr: working with avd and creating directory in sdcard

Tags: android, directory, android-virtual-device

(1)  i wrote a code to create a new file in sdcard ,i checked that card is mounted but i don't  know how to see the file which is created in emulator. skin used is wvga800

(2) i want to create new directory in sdcard but file.mkdir() returns false and is it necessary that manifest file has to be written for checking output on avd also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the sdcard directory using `adb shell`. Just browse to the `/sdcard` directory.

To write to the sdcard, make sure your AndroidManifest has the proper permission declared. In this case,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

should be enough.

Comment: i have written the code on ide and i executed it ,for this also manifest file has to be there?

Comment: If you use an IDE like Eclipse, the AndroidManifest.xml file will be generated automaticaly, but it doesn't mean you don't need to edit it. It is on the root directory of the project. Try to find it and check if the permission described above has been declared.

Comment: i did so but no change ,i wrote the following code                                                          String state=Environment.getExternalStorageState();
      if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
      {
        File folder=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/vid");
       if( folder.canWrite()){
      boolean happen =folder.mkdirs();    then there is code which displays the yes if happen=true and no if happen =false, and it displays false

Comment: Does the "/vid" directory exists? What are the permissions of this folder?

Comment: I did a sample code here and I'm able to reproduce your issue. I'm trying to figure out what's the problem, but had no luck so far... =/

Comment: Oh, i fount the problem! The point is that `folder.canWrite()` will only return true if the folder already exists. If you run `folder.mkdirs()` and then check for `folder.canWrite()` it will return true. The correct verification is to check if `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is writable, and then call `mkdirs()` to `folder`.

Comment: i think i was doing a foolish mistake,when i ran the code once it showed yes and again when i ran it showed no ,mkdirs i suppose returned false second time because folder was already created once . is it so?

Comment: That's right! If the folder is already there, `mkdirs()` will return false.

Comment: but i cant see any new folder in avd

Comment: Check my sample code. You can download it from here http://www.mediafire.com/?j5jq9ozu0n4333z . With this code I can successfully create the `vid/` folder inside the sdcard.

Comment: i am searching for the folder in avd ,does it shows up there? or there some other way i can see for that,thanks a lot for the help

Comment: If you use the file explorer in DDMS you will see that the folder is there (for me, it's /mnt/sdcard/vid but it depends on the Android). If you test it in a real phone instead of avd, you can just mount the sdcard and browse to that folder.

Comment: No problem! Just don't forget to accept the answer if it was really helpful to you! =)